# Failed to execute user defined function

Tags: scala, udf

I have the following UDF:

```
val jac_index:(Array[String],Array[String])=>Float=(Sq1:Array[String],Sq2:Array[String])=>
{
    val Sq3=Sq1.intersect(Sq2)
    val Sq4=Sq1.union(Sq2).distinct
    if (!Sq4.isEmpty) Sq3.length.toFloat/Sq4.length.toFloat else 0F
}
val jacUDF=udf(jac_index)
```

and when I execute the following sentence

```
val movie_jac_df=movie_pairs_df.withColumn("jac",jacUDF(movie_pairs_df("name"),movie_pairs_df("name2")))
```

I get the error "Failed to execute user defined function"

the schema of **movie_pairs_df** is the following

```
root
 |-- movie: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- movie2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

So what's the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark's DataFrames model Array columns as `mutable.WrappedArray`, which means your UDF should take two WrappedArrays as its input;

If you change `jac_index` to expect two such arrays:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val jac_index: (mutable.WrappedArray[String], mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => Float = 
  (Sq1, Sq2) => { /* same implementation */ }
```

This will work as expected.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

define the udf as below

```
val jacUDF = udf((Sq1:mutable.WrappedArray[String], Sq2:mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  val Sq3=Sq1.intersect(Sq2)
  val Sq4=Sq1.union(Sq2).distinct
  if (!Sq4.isEmpty) Sq3.length.toFloat/Sq4.length.toFloat else 0F
})
```